# Linkedin PHP Login API Call

Tags: php, authentication, linkedin-api

I'm using a class found on Github (Happyr\Linkedin) to connect to Linkedin API and create a login. It worked fine, with no problem whatsoever until it didn't work anymore, but without doing any changes at all.

This is my call code:

```
$linkedIn=new Happyr\LinkedIn\LinkedIn('apikey', 'apisecret');
```

session_start();

```
if ($linkedIn->isAuthenticated() && isset($_GET['code'])) {

    $user=$linkedIn->get('v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName,id,picture-url)');
    if ($user){
      $_user = User::where('linkedin_id', $user['id'])->first();

      if (!$_user) {
        //create user and login
        header("Location: search.php");
        exit();
      } else {
        //login user
        header("Location: search.php");
        exit();
      }
    }
```

What I'm receiving is an exception in one of the vendor packages:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Http\Client\Exception\NetworkException: Could not resolve host: www.linkedin.com in /var/www/html/vendor/php-http/curl-client/src/Client.php:134 Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/happyr/linkedin-api-client/src/Http/RequestManager.php(37): Http\Client\Curl\Client->sendRequest(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request))
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/happyr/linkedin-api-client/src/Authenticator.php(124): Happyr\LinkedIn\Http\RequestManager->sendRequest('POST', 'https://www.lin...', Array, 'grant_type=auth...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/happyr/linkedin-api-client/src/Authenticator.php(76): Happyr\LinkedIn\Authenticator->getAccessTokenFromCode(Object(Happyr\LinkedIn\Http\UrlGenerator), 'AQTWSqlSdfv3Fy_...')
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/happyr/linkedin-api-client/src/LinkedIn.php(293): Happyr\LinkedIn\Authenticator->fetchNewAccessToken(Object(Happyr\LinkedIn\Http\UrlGenerator))
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/happyr/linkedin-api-client/src/LinkedIn.php(95): Happyr\LinkedIn\LinkedIn->getAccessToken()
#5 /var/www/html/index.php(9): Happ in /var/www/html/vendor/happyr/linkedin-api-client/src/Authenticator.php on line 128
```

Any idea on how can I solve this?

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with your network configuration. Looks like for whatever reason you script can not find host `www.linkedin.com`

Comment: @E_p I pinged linkedin from the server, looks like it is ok. What could be wrong in network configuration? The only activity was that the Digital Ocean Droplet was closed for several hours, closed by DO staff due to payment. Could something happened when the droplet is closed that could affect the network configuration?

Comment: For starters it can be proxy and firewall. Than you need to look in too your php configuration some features/modules can be turned off.

Comment: You can also try to pass `CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE =>  false` and `CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT =>  2` as part of your curl options

Answer (score 1):

Update you composer.lock file and try again.

Comment: this sounds more like a comment.